# How to replace 2 backslashes in javascript with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I replace 2 forward slashes with let's say 4 backslashes using regex?
I tried several variations on the code below. I've to admit that I have no experience with RegEx.
Thx!

```
path = "//computerName/C$/folder";
path = path.replace(/\//g, "\\"); // this works for 1 slash
path = path.replace(/\/\//g, "\\\\"); // here I need to replaces 2 slashes with 4
```

The result should be:

```
"\\\\computerName\\C$\\folder"
```

Comment: `path = path.replace(/\/\//g, "\\\\");` or `path = path.replace(/\/\//g, "\\\\\\\\");`

Comment: Sorry that was a copy paste error. Of course I replace it with "\\\\". I update my question.

Comment: Backslashes are interpreted twice: once by the javascript interpreter, and once by the regex

Comment: @Avinash: Thx, but that didn`t work.

Comment: like this? path.replace(/\//g, "\\\\");

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below capture group for all occurrences of double forward slashes:

```
path.replace(/(\/\/)/g, "\\\\\\\\");
```